# Translating my custom files

Tags: product-list

[image]Hi I added this code in my list.phtml file in order to add some info in my product list grid page (see picture attached) and added some div class so that I can change the style and move it around. I know it is probably not the correct way however it works. Now the problem is that I am unable to translate this part in french. Is there a way I can do this? I tried inline and .csv files in my locale but doesn't work and I am pretty sure it is because my codes below are not the correct way to do it. Please help. Thank you

Comment: <div class="msrp">
Retail Price: <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getMsrp(),true,false); ?>
</div>

<div class="qtyleftgrid">
<?php $qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getStockQty(); ?>
<?php if ($qty): ?>
Qty Left: <?php echo $qty; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    SOLD OUT
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div class="yourprice">
Our Price
</div>

Answer (score 1):

Any text that needs to be translated should be passed through the translate helper. In your template file instead of echoing your text as a string you need to use the translate function on the block. e.g

```
<div><?php echo $this->__('translated text goes here'); ?></div>
```

If you do this you should be able to translate the text using your locale csv files.

Comment: Thankyou very much. It works!!!